# Load page content without re-loading banner

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

A while ago I had a website that would load certain parts of it when a url was clicked. for example:

www.mysite.com/index.php would turn into www.mysite.com/index?contact.php

and the anchor looked like `<a href="index?contact.php">Contact</a>`

The header, nav bar and footer would not load again, but the content of "index" would be replaced by the content of "Contact"

I just can't remember the script that would make the anchor replace the PHP file that was loaded with the requested one from the anchor.

The index file looked something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>


<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<title>My Site</title>
<style>
<?php include 'css/styles.css'; ?>
</style>
</head>

<body>
<script here>
<a href="index?contact.php">Contact</a>
<a href="index?contact.php">Store</a>
<a href="index?contact.php">Stuff</a>
</body>
</html>
```

and each of the "php" files would then load a different set of:

```
<div id="div_1"></div>
<div id="div_2"></div>
<div id="div_3"></div>
```

And it all pulled from one CSS.

I hope I was clear enough in what I am trying to accomplish, and someone can help me out.

Comment: A very simple implementation would be to just have each individual php file echo out their html structure, and have an ajax call on the client request the appropriate file, then just replace the innerhtml property in the content container. This wouldn't actually replace your urls, but the page wouldn't have to refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using AJAX / XMLHttpRequest.
If you're not using a js-library like jQuery the pure js would be something like this:

```
function requestPage(requestPage) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // what will we do with the response?
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        } else {
            // page could not be loaded/requested
            document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = "Page not found.";
        }
    }
    // actuall request
    xmlhttp.open("GET", requestPage, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
var anchors = document.querySelectorAll("a");
for(var index = 0; index < anchors.length; index++) {
    anchors[index].addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        event.prefentDefault();
        requestPage(event.target.href);
    });
}
```

This code assumes that you've got an element with the id "#content" where the content of the page should load.
A little reference of what is possible and how to use the js XMLHttpRequest Object: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp

Comment: What I am not understanding is how can I make that function pick a php file to load from.

Also, will I need to have that same function once for every needed page?

Comment: You only need this single function. Currently it tries to load the file which the href refers to so either you change the hrefs to i.e. "contact.php" or you need to filter/regex the actual filename inside of the click-event.